# how to change color in cell without typing 25 functions

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, queryselector

i have a problem with table

```
<td id="1" onclick="func1()">1</td> 
<td id="2" onclick="func1()">2</td> 
<td id="3">3</td> <td id="4">4</td> 
<td id="5">5</td>
```

and i want to change color in one cell without give another id to cell and type x5 this same function to another cell, okay, this is a js code:

```
function func1() {
  let table = document.querySelector("td");     
  alert("pole" + table + "nacisniete");      
  table.style.backgroundColor = "grey"; 
}
```

if i clicked cell 2, cell1 change color, i want to have 1 function and this must change a color in selected cell

*Sorry for my english, im form poland*

i want to write another id to another cell and i must have a 25 functions for this work, so i pick queryselector to pick a one cell but this dont work, i picked cell2 and change color to cell1[image]

Comment: thank you for repair this question, i have an error and i must delete spaces in code :<

Comment: From your description it's not clear what you are actually trying to achieve. What should happen if you click the cell 1? What should happen if you click cell 2 afterwards?

Comment: if i click cell 1 the cell 1 change color to gray, if i click cell 5 then cell 5 change color to grey, i want to do this without giving cell another id and white 5 functions, optimalize site. cell3 clicked > cell3 color changed

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a function on each TD, I'm using document.querySelectorALL to loop through the TDs and give each an event listener. Also, I'm adding a class instead of changing it in javascript as this will give you more options down the road. I commented out two lines these lines will remove the background on a td that has already been clicked so only one can be clicked at a time. You don't need that but I wasn't sure if that was what you wanted or not.

```js
let tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");
tds.forEach((td) => {
  td.addEventListener("click",() =>{
     //let active = document.querySelector("td.active");
     //if(active) active.classList.remove("active");
     td.classList.add("active");
  });
});
```

```css
td.active{
  background:gray
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<td>1</td> 
<td>2</td> 
<td>3</td> <td>4</td> 
<td>5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add event listener to the parent element: "myTable" and use event.target to add class to the currently clicked cell

```js
const table = document.getElementById("myTable");

table.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
 console.log(event.target);
 event.target.classList.add("active");
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
}

td.active{
 background-color:grey
}

td:hover {
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```